# Alternative to UITableView.Begin/EndUpdates

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

We have a custom MonoTouch Dialog (MT D) Element that we want to expand as we type into it.

We experienced the common MT D issue of the height not recalculating. The common solution for that is to call

```
this.GetContainerTableView().BeginUpdates();
this.GetContainerTableView().EndUpdates();
```

Stack OverFlow Question

[Monotouch: Force UITableView to recalculate height of each cell without reloading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514391/monotouch-force-uitableview-to-recalculate-height-of-each-cell-without-reloadin/14546691)

This has always worked fine for us if even it does smell of HACK. However a user is reporting an issue on their iPhone X that means the whole MT D container (the UITableView) is being scrolled every time which causes the screen to jump.

I have tried temporarily disabling the scroll on the Element's Container and on the immediate RootElement but that made no difference.

Can anyone suggest something to stop the jumping?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried setting scroll position back to it values before Begin and EndUpdates but was getting exceptions trying to hook the scroll event

```
UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureEventAndDelegateAreNotMismatched
```

However this suggestion does teh resetting without using Scroll Event. Thanks Kyle Shank

http://www.kyleshank.com/2015/12/05/prevent-uitableview-from-scrolling-during-updates.html

Note:
I spent about a few hours trying to hack my way out of this problem before I posted to SO . In writing the question I found the Kyke Shank solution but decided we'd all be better off if I still wrote up as a question and subsequent answer.